# how to check all column cell of datagridview? if one or more cell is empty, it will return a value?

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I want to check the cells of my datagridview. 
also if atleast one of the cell is empty, it will return "false"

and so, I have this method WHICH is i knew is not correct. 
since if ever the last item in the array has value, it will make "checking" a true.
I just cant get the correct code or logic for what i plan to make.

```
public void checker()
    {
        string[] check = new string[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            check[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        }
        for (int e = 0; e < check.Length; e++)
        {
            if (check[e] == null)
            {
                checking = "false";
            }
            else
            {
                checking = "true";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how about `if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null){ checking = false; break; }` Once it finds a null value, it will exit the loop. You dno't need the `string[]`

Comment: that saved me a lot of time thanks

Comment: @Roy whats the reason behind deleting your other question?

Comment: sorry but I had reasons. but first let me thank everyone who answered. i had to delete the question because, i realize that no matter what i do in this approach, it will never run the program im working on bugless(on this part) the part where i expect the bugs will appear is on the "checking" on the other form. since the program im working on is a management system, naturally this will handle a lot of names simultaneously. assigning checking in 1 example is ok but, if the program assigned checking in 2 or more names, problems will occur. thats what my logic tells.

Comment: why i deleted the question? because i want to avoid misleading other readers first, on my question. second, on my codes. third, on the concept and the answer. because I myself encounter this problems on in another forum. kinda hard to explain but i wish you would understand. i am also sorry. i appreciate your answer but as soon as i thoroughly study your answer, thats when i realize the wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just return from the function the very first time you find an empty cell. You could try using the following approach:

```
public void checker()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
        var value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
         {
            checking = false;
            return;
         }
      }

      // If we have reached this far, then none of the cells were empty.
      checking = true;
   }
```